# functional calculus for non-unital $C^*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $A$ is a non-unital $C^*$ algebra,$a$ is a normal element of $A$, there is a $*$ isometric isomorphism from $C_0(\sigma_{A}(a))$ to $C^*(a)$.

I have a question:what is the set of $C_0(\sigma_{A}(a))$?Is it the set of all continuous functions $f$ defined on $\sigma_{A}(a) $  which vanish at infinity?  or besides, we need $f(0)=0$? see [continuous functional calculus for nonunital $c^*$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280917/continuous-functional-calculus-for-nonunital-c-algebras)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's just bad notation. When $A$ is not unital and you consider the C$^*$-algebra generated by $a$ in $A$, it cannot contain the unit of $A$. So when $a$ is normal C$^*(a)$ is the closure of the span of the words in $a$ and $a^*$, without constants.

The spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is compact, so $C(\sigma(A))$ is unital. For the identification $C^*(a)\simeq C_0(\sigma(a))$, one is taking the continuous functions where $f(0)=0$. That's what the subscript means. It's bad notation because it is **not** the set of functions that vanish at infinity.

Comment: So $C_0(\sigma(a))$ is the set of continuous functions $f$ defined on  $\sigma(a)$ such that $f(0)=0$?

Comment: Not usually, but it is in what you wrote. It's a really bad choice of notation.

Comment: what is the standard notaion when we talk about the functional calculus for the non-unital $C^*$ algebras?

Comment: Standard notation for what ?